# Curl response headers on error

Tags: php, http, rest, curl, header

I'm working on PHP client for my API and I'm using Curl to do the request. All goes well but when there is a response http code of 400 or higher I can't seem to get the headers from the response.

To get the headers from all responses is needed because my API adds an extra header to the response with more information about what went wrong.

If there a way to always get the headers from the response in Curl?

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Convert headers to curlopts
    $headers_new = array();
    foreach($headers as $key => $value){
        if(isset($this->_header_to_curlopt[$key])){
            switch($key) {
                case self::HEADER_AUTHORIZATION:
                    if(strstr($value, 'Basic')) {
                        $value = base64_decode(trim(str_replace('Basic ', '', $value)));
                    }
                    break;
                case self::HEADER_COOKIE:
                    if(is_array($value)) {
                        $value = $this->cookieStringToArray($value);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            curl_setopt($ch, $this->_header_to_curlopt[$key], $value);
            unset($this->_requestHeaders[$key]);
        }else{
            $headers_new[] = $key . ': ' . $value;
        }
    }
    $headers = $headers_new;

    // Add length header if it is not set
    if(!isset($headers[self::HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH])){
        if(is_array($data)) {
            $headers[self::HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH] = strlen(http_build_query($data, '', '&'));
        } else {
            $headers[self::HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH] = strlen($data);
        }
    }

    // Set headers
    if(count($headers)){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        // Don't output content
    curl_setopt($ch ,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);        // Timeout

    switch($method){
        case self::METHOD_POST:
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case self::METHOD_GET:
            if(count($this->_data)) {
                $separator = strstr($url, '?') ? '&' : '?';
                $url .= $separator . http_build_query($this->_data, '', '&');
            }
            break;
        default:
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
            break;
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

    // Use SSL
    if(strtolower(substr($url, 0, 5)) == 'https') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    }
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    // Separate content and headers
    $result = str_replace("\r\n\r\nHTTP/", "\r\nHTTP/", $result);
    $parts = explode("\r\n\r\n",$result);
    $headers = array_shift($parts);
    $result = implode("\r\n\r\n", $parts);
```

Comment: You might should not be sending custom headers.  Probably would be better off sending the error string as the response body.  And how are you getting the headers on responses of less than 400?  Looking through the cURL php docs, I'm not seeing anything for getting response headers.  Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: You can try adding the error codes as success using the setting CURLOPT_HTTP200ALIASES.

Comment: @RageZ I've added the curl part of my code

Comment: @Corbin Then you have the same problem. Curl doesn't return any content/headers when the http code of the response is 400 or more.

Comment: @Sjoerd I want my API to be RESTful so that's something I don't want to do.

Comment: I found the problem.
The line causing this problems was this:

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);

Answer (score 2):

You should set the `CURLOPT_HEADER` flag, you can get the HTTP status code using [`curl_getinfo`](http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/function.curl-getinfo.php).

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init('http://yoururl/'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
$c = curl_exec($ch); 
echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

---

from your code

```
$ch = curl_init();

// Convert headers to curlopts
$headers_new = array();
foreach($headers as $key => $value){
    if(isset($this->_header_to_curlopt[$key])){
        switch($key) {
            case self::HEADER_AUTHORIZATION:
                if(strstr($value, 'Basic')) {
                    $value = base64_decode(trim(str_replace('Basic ', '', $value)));
                }
                break;
            case self::HEADER_COOKIE:
                if(is_array($value)) {
                    $value = $this->cookieStringToArray($value);
                }
                break;
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, $this->_header_to_curlopt[$key], $value);
        unset($this->_requestHeaders[$key]);
    }else{
        $headers_new[] = $key . ': ' . $value;
    }
}
$headers = $headers_new;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
// Add length header if it is not set
if(!isset($headers[self::HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH])){
    if(is_array($data)) {
        $headers[self::HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH] = strlen(http_build_query($data, '', '&'));
    } else {
        $headers[self::HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH] = strlen($data);
    }
}

// Set headers
if(count($headers)){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        // Don't output content
curl_setopt($ch ,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);        // Timeout

switch($method){
    case self::METHOD_POST:
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        break;
    case self::METHOD_GET:
        if(count($this->_data)) {
            $separator = strstr($url, '?') ? '&' : '?';
            $url .= $separator . http_build_query($this->_data, '', '&');
        }
        break;
    default:
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
        break;
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

// Use SSL
if(strtolower(substr($url, 0, 5)) == 'https') {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
}
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

// Separate content and headers
$result = str_replace("\r\n\r\nHTTP/", "\r\nHTTP/", $result);
$parts = explode("\r\n\r\n",$result);
$headers = array_shift($parts);
$result = implode("\r\n\r\n", $parts);
```